# Программа на C# добавляет, но не редактирует и не удаляет данные из базы данных

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, sql-server

Сделал в Visual Studio на С# программу предназначенную для записи, редактирования и удаления данных из однотабличной базы данных Microsoft SQL Server

Программа успешно записывает новые данные в таблицу базы данных, но при попытке удалить или отредактировать данные в какой-либо из строк таблицы появляется сообщение:
"Для обновления требуется действительный UpdateCommand при передачи коллекции DataRow с измененными строками."
То есть в таблицу самого приложения в DataGridView изменения записываются, но при попытке сохранить это изменение кликом по кнопке появляется это сообщение, а в базе данных ничего не меняется

При попытке удалить всю строку целиком клавишей из BindingNavigator никаких сообщений не появляется, строка в таблице приложения удаляется, но в базе данных ничего не меняется

В итоге на данный момент функционирует лишь внесение новых данных в базу данных

Часть кода программы:

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'spisok_zakazovDataSet.Table_1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.table_1TableAdapter.Fill(this.spisok_zakazovDataSet.Table_1);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.table1BindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.table_1TableAdapter.Update(this.spisok_zakazovDataSet.Table_1);
            MessageBox.Show("Update successful");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Update failed");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Программа + база данных целиком: https://yadi.sk/d/8licJpe13Hnq5a

Comment: Что непонятно из ошибки? Задайте `tableAdapter.UpdateCommand = "update ..."` с кодом sql для обновления таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, задаются ли в базе данных Id для создаваемых записей. 
Если нет, настройте автоинкремент, и пересоздайте контрол, через который редактируете источник данных.